# onClick doesn't work on <button> but work on <a>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

trying to trigger an event onClick, it works when i use "a" tag but when i use button it doesn't :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.backwardWeek = this.backwardWeek.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      displayedWeek: 0,
      inputs: []

    }; 
backwardWeek() {
    this.state.displayedWeek = this.state.displayedWeek - 1;   
   }

render(){

return (   
  <button onClick={this.backwardWeek}>  <span className="glyphicon glyphicon- 
   arrow-left" /></button> 
  );
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to log in backwardWeek?

Comment: That's not how you set state. use this.setState

Comment: Never modify your state directly like that. You must always use setState.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change component's state, you have to use `this.setState`.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.backwardWeek = this.backwardWeek.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      displayedWeek: 0,
      inputs: []

    }; 
backwardWeek() {
    this.setState({
      displayedWeek: this.state.displayedWeek - 1
    }) // notice the difference
   }

render(){

return (   
  <button onClick={this.backwardWeek}>  <span className="glyphicon glyphicon- 
   arrow-left" /></button> 
  ); // notice the difference
```

Comment: Please dont just post answers, exaplain *what* and *why* you did something :)

Comment: Also, do not bind there, that is not logic you should apply there.

Comment: @EdwinHarly, oh how did I miss that. Will edit the answer. Thank you.

Comment: hey guys you re abusing a little bit i forget to use the setState and it works Thank you tryzniak thank you very much man

Answer (score 1):

When you have to update the state of component, react component has a method setState() which you can use to do so.